# How to get the current Column Index while editing a cell in DataGridView using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with 5 columns.
The Cells of Columns 1 and 5 are ComboBoxes.
I have a function that runs whenever I change any of these ComboBoxes.

Now, for the function to run properly, I have to get which Column does the ComboBox that I have edited belongs to.

Its like, when I change the ComboBox that belongs to Column 1, `Function 1` runs.
When I change the ComboBox that belongs to Column 5, `Function 2` runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or

```
DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
```

Then if your have a predefined columns in `DataGridView`(for example name of column will be `DataGridView_ComboBoxOne`) and don't want hardcode a compare of indexes

You can use like this:

```
Select case DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex 
    Case DataGridView_ComboBoxOne.Index
        Function1()
    Case DataGridView_ComboBoxTwo.Index
        Function2()
    Case Else
        'Update of other columns
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you.
'CurrentCell.ColumnIndex' and 'CurrentCellAddress.Y' works the same.
But I will use 'CurrentCell.ColumIndex' because it is more 'readable'.
I also tested your other code and it also works great.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim columnIndex as Integer

columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex
```

This is the straight way to get the column index without using current cell. Use it under DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick.

Answer (score 1):

Ah silly me,

```
DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.X 'Column  
DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress.Y 'Row
```

Comment: Really, great and new info, ]Thanks[    
^_^